# How to dismiss keyboard from textfield that's inside tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

[image]

hi, please refer to image above! I am not sure how to dismiss the keyboard after I am done entering infomation in the textfield that is inside the tableviewcell.

Comment: Can you share some code with us?

Comment: nvm I figured it out! ill post below

Answer (score 1):

Tried doing this and it worked! Created an inputAccessoryView and added it to the keyboard. in swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-toolbar-above-the-keyboard-using-inputaccessoryview

In objective c:

```
UIToolbar * bar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
            UIBarButtonItem * done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                     target:self
                                                                     action:@selector(doneBtn)];
           // bar.items = [done];
            NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [arr addObject:done];
            bar.items = arr;
           // bar.sizeToFit()
            [bar sizeToFit];
            bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor;
            cell.fieldTextField.inputAccessoryView = bar;
```

Comment: not wrong..:) but this introduces a "Done" button which is indirectly dismissing the keyboard because this may cause to resign the first responder and so the textfield is forced to [cell endEditing:YES].

Comment: ^^ which is what i was looking for actually, since now, after i am done editing the textfield, i can click the done button and that dismisses the keyboard/keypad